# Always display double time menu item at Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu, menuitem

I just want to set an `menu` at `action bar`. It works but in a wrong way.
  just like this:
[image]

[image]

I searched the problem almost all the night, but did not find any answer.
Here is my code for the `onCreatOptionsMenu` method at fragment:

```
 public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu,MenuInflater inflater) {
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_detail,menu);
            MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
            ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(shareItem);
            mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareForecastIntent());
        }
```

**And here is the activity's code:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
    //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.detailfragment, new DetailActivityFragment())
            .commit();
}
```

**Here is my menu XML:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       tools:context="com.example.android.sunshine.app.DetailActivity.DetailActivityFragment">
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Share"
    app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"         />
   <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

**Here is my activity's layout:**

```
<fragment 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/detailfragment"
                                android:name="com.example.android.sunshine.app.DetailActivity$DetailActivityFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_detail"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"/>
```

**Fragment layout:**

```
<FrameLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/detailText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hello boy"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fragments onCreate view

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);    
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return rootView;   

}
```

and in `onCreateOptionsMenu`

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_detail, menu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly would you like your menu bar to look like? 

So, right now you have two 'share' icons, followed by a 'more' icon, and some empty space (or darker color). 

Please be a little bit more descriptive.

Comment: Thanks for your attention.  I just want only one share button at menu bar,and my menu xml file is also just define only one. But it always display two share button at actionbar. You can look over my picture in the question.